Why does my code not run an if statement after the while loop?
from random import randint
print("Get 7+ right to win.")
cycle = 0
count = 1

def FUNC():
    global count
    global cycle
    rand = randint(1,10)
    print(rand)
    Var0 = int(input("Choose 1-10  "))
    if Var0 == rand:
        print("Good!")
        count += 1
        cycle += 1
    else:
        print("Sorry!")
        cycle += 1

while cycle < 10:
    FUNC()

if cycle > 10:
    if count >= 7:
        print("You win")
    elif count < 7:
        print(f"You lose! Count = {count}")

This is my guessing game. But for some reason the score win or loss thing doesn't run.
I tried by getting everything right, nothing right, adjusting the code but nothing.
Here is what I get from console:
Choose 1-10  5
Good!
10
Choose 1-10  10
Good!

Process finished with exit code 0


Why do you think you need that if statement? It's just checking the condition that causes the loop to stop. But if you get out of the loop you know that the condition has been met.

^^ What moken said.. cycle never reaches 11.  But the way your code is written, you don't actually need that IF at all.  You are looping endlessly in the while loop, until cycle == 10, then it will exit the loop.  So cycle can never be anything other than 10 following the loop.

Aside: Don't duplicate the cycle += 1 code in both if and else. It should be done unconditionally.

Also, why put the cycle counter in the function at all? Why not just for _ in range(10): FUNC()? Can the function increment cycle by more or less than 1 in some conditions?

This seems like a good time to learn basic debugging. You can simply put print(cycle) before the if statement to see why the condition is failing.

https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

your output is incorrect, it doesnt fit well with your code

The condition cycle > 10 will never be True

As written, your program never increments cycle to more than 10, thus your cycle > 10 condition is always false and nothing in the conditional is evaluated.
If you remove that pointless conditional and just evaluate the following, you might see what you intended:
if count >= 7:
    print("You win")
elif count < 7:
    print(f"You lose! Count = {count}")

